# What is the condition for completion handler of basic_stream_socket::async_write_some to be called?

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, asio

[The documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html) for `basic_stream_socket::async_write_some` states, that the completion handler is called "when the write operation completes". But what exactly does that mean? I can think at least of two things

- when the kernel (networking stack in particular) takes responsibility for the data
- when the networking stack on the remote end has acknowledged (as in TCP ACK) the data, that was sent and the acknowledgement has reached the local networking stack

Comment: I suppose it's easy to detect by having a client ack a package really slowly?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to come up with a test program:

**[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20788783c2548321)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto now       = &std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
auto sleep_for = [](auto dur) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(dur); };
auto timestamp = [start = now()] { return (now() - start)/1.0ms; };

int main() {
    static constexpr size_t msglen = 16 << 20; // 16 mib
    thread_pool io(1);
    tcp::acceptor a(io, {{}, 7878});
    a.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    a.listen();

#define CHECKED_OPTION(s, name, requested) do { \
    tcp::socket::name option(requested); \
    /*s.set_option(option);*/ \
    s.get_option(option); \
    std::cout << " " << #name << ":" << option.value(); \
} while (0)

    a.async_accept([=](error_code ec, tcp::socket&& con) {
        std::cout << timestamp() << "ms accept " << ec.message();
        std::cout << " " << con.remote_endpoint(ec);

        con.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
        CHECKED_OPTION(con, receive_buffer_size, 100);
        CHECKED_OPTION(con, send_buffer_size, 100);

        std::cout << std::endl;

        if (!ec) {
            sleep_for(1s);
            std::cout << timestamp() << "ms start write" << std::endl;
            auto xfr = con.write_some(buffer(std::string(msglen, '*')), ec);
            std::cout << timestamp() << "ms write completed: " << xfr << "/" << msglen << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    });

    {
        tcp::socket s(io);
        sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << timestamp() << "ms connecting" << std::endl;
        s.connect({{}, 7878});
        std::cout << timestamp() << "ms connected";
        CHECKED_OPTION(s, receive_buffer_size, 100);
        CHECKED_OPTION(s, send_buffer_size, 100);
        std::cout << std::endl;

        sleep_for(3s);
        std::cout << timestamp() << "ms disconnecting" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << timestamp() << "ms disconnected" << std::endl;

    a.cancel();
    io.join();
}
```

Note how we make sure to send more data than is being read by a wide margin to saturate any buffering involved. (We actually donot read any data from the client socket at all)

It prints (on Coliru):

```
1000.48ms connecting
1001.07ms connected receive_buffer_size:530904 send_buffer_size:1313280
1001.23ms accept Success 127.0.0.1:41614 receive_buffer_size:531000 send_buffer_size:1313280
2001.64ms start write
4001.37ms disconnecting
4001.62ms disconnected
4013.33ms write completed: 4481610/16777216 (Success)
```

It is clear that

- write_some is only complete when the packages are ACK-ed, and the actual number of bytes transferred is returned.
- the kernel ACKs packages independently of the application layer

> In fact the packages may arrive out of order, in which case the kernel ACKs them individually before the sequencing for the application to read the data via the socket API.

### Buffering

Buffering is inevitable, but can be tuned within limits. E.g. uncommenting this line from the CHECKED_OPTION macro:

```
s.set_option(option); \
```

Gives different output ([Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)):

```
1000.44ms connecting
1001.08ms connected receive_buffer_size:1152 send_buffer_size:2304
1001.31ms accept Success 127.0.0.1:41618 receive_buffer_size:1152 send_buffer_size:2304
2001.88ms start write
4001.42ms disconnecting
4001.61ms disconnected
4008.21ms write completed: 43776/16777216 (Success)
```

Comment: Pertinent answer, as always. Out of context, why "16 << 20" in
    `static constexpr size_t msglen = 16 << 20; // 16 mib`
?

Comment: @JeanDavy I don't think `16777216` is as expressive, and I hate tedious expressions like `16 * 1024 * 1024`. It's just a bit lazy, I guess :)

Comment: Ah... OK... Reminiscence of "C" glorious days ? ;-)

Comment: @JeanDavy Doing bitshifts works the same in many languages. It's just a mathism to read `1<<n` as `2^n` I guess.